# Android Emulator - testing bad network conditions and logcat

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-logcat

I am using the Android emulator to test testing my mobile application and I am emulating bad network conditions. I am doing this by using `telnet`, e.g. `telnet localhost 5554` and then setting the network speed and delay to the desired values, e.g. `network speed 1`, `network delay 30000`.

My problem is my mobile application has an issue that only occurs under bad network conditions, but I can't debug it because as soon I emulate bad network conditions, `logcat` stops printing output.

Any ideas on how I can get `logcat` to work in this scenario?.

Comment: Why should logcat be related to network-speed?

Comment: @Rafael T - I don't think it should, but it seems that every time I change the emulator settings, my debug output stops being printed to the logcat console.

Comment: have you tried to type `adb logcat` in the console? often when Eclipse refuses to show me logcat this still works

Comment: and adb devices still shows your device? It may be the case that you loose the connection to adb on port 5554

Comment: adb devices still shows my device.

Comment: sorry then, I'm out of ideas, too. Only thing I can think of is that the delay is too much for logcat, but its really just a guess and I have no idea why.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Rafael T.

Comment: You can also try to type `adb kill-server` and adb `start-server` to make it work again